# Why are my queries failing?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Here is my code where I am trying to execute my queries:

```
foreach ($ageGroups as $ageGroup) {
    if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO national_age_gender_demographics (age_group, male_pop, female_pop, both_pop, male_percent, female_percent, both_percent, males_per_100_females) VALUES(". $ageGroup[0].", ".$ageGroup[1].", ".$ageGroup[2].", ".$ageGroup[3].", ".$ageGroup[4].", ".$ageGroup[5].", ".$ageGroup[6].", ".$ageGroup[7].")")) {
        printf("Created row");
    }
}
```

$ageGroups is an array of arrays containing sub-arrays for each row of my table.

So, could you please help me out here?

Comment: you can ask your DBMS `mysqli_error_list()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error-list.php

Comment: Do you get an error messages? Where are your error handlers? Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Comment: Help yourself by looking at the generated SQL, firing the queries by hand if need be so you can get interactive feedback and using Mysql's general query log -- or any combination of the above.

Comment: You shouldn't have to be storing the `both_pop` and `both_percent` in your table. You can work that out in your PHP code after you have queries for those rows.

Comment: your code is simply assuming success. **NEVER* assume success when dealing with external resources. always check return values

Comment: Please please please use prepared statements!  Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.  This is 2013, SQL injections really shouldn't exist anymore when the solution to them is so simple. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the values on single quotes, like this:

```
VALUES('". $ageGroup[0]."', '".$ageGroup[1]."', '".$ageGroup[2]."', '". //etc
```

Comment: Nelson is correct. You might also look into executing a var_dump on your sql statements if they give you any trouble. You may also want to echo $mysqli->error on failure for debugging.

Comment: Well the data look like INT to me (male_pop, female_pop, etc

Comment: @F.C. You can enclose INT fields in single quotes with MySQL with no problem.

Comment: @Nelson you're right, I did not know that.

Comment: This worked, along with removing the dots.  Thanks.